# Why is Spring Boot excluding http-client from spring-rabbit?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-amqp.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>http-client</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Why is this dependency excluded? I am just wondering since now, every time we want to update Boot version, we need to look which `http-client` version is used in `spring-rabbit` so we import the same version to avoid versioning issues.

I am sure there is a reason, but I cannot figure out what it is, could a maintainer provide some clarification please?

Comment: Doesn't Rabbit use AMQP protocol?  Why would it need an HTTP client?

Comment: I need to fetch all queues from the server. I couldn't find an appropriate method for that on AMQP protocol, but HTTP client does provide this method.